# What books to start on web programming for an experienced non-web programmer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, dhtml

> **No surprise here, possible dupes:**
>
> [Good Books for Learning Web Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931557/good-books-resources-for-learning-web-programming)
>   [Required Reading for a Soon to be Web Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911343/required-reading-for-a-soon-to-be-web-developer)
>   and there will be more.

For a personal project, I'm starting to do some web programming using Django. I've programmed since I was very young on several languages, mostly Pascal/Delphi, C/C++, SQL Python (sometimes in other languages such as Java, PHP or Perl) so I'm not a newbie programmer, but apart from basic HTML I've little experience on the front-end side of web programming (CSS, HTML, Javascript and AJAX) because on my former professional projects if there was web programming somebody would do the frontend part.

I'm loving the Django framework but I feel very limited and lost with the frontend part and would like to improve on it. What books that wont lose 100 pages explaining what a variable or a function is would you recommend? (better if all of these technologies are covered together, but different books on each topic is Ok too)

Comment: Yes, I saw these questions. But the first link is a question of a newbie programmer, the second one specifically states that he doesn't want books about frameworks or technologies but "challengues and terminology". I *do* want books about technologies and frameoworks, so I don't think this is a dupe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can recommend a few that I usually provide my Jr. web developers, and that I find my self referencing from time to time.  These are create for basic web development, and depending on your back end server environment, you may want to purchase a books on IIS and C#, or Apache and PHP etc.

1. [Bulletproof Web Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321346939)  by Dan Cedarholm
2. [CSS Mastery:](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596145) Advanced Web Standards Solutions
3. [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101996)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll take a look at those books (I see the Javascript one referred a lot.) I do have some experience on backend programming (PHP) and Apache, as well as webservices, my weak point is HTML/CSS/Javascript/Ajax.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is:
Go over to the [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/) tutorials on all these subjects. They will guide you through the basics to the more advanced stuff. But IMO web design needs a good eye for design; this is something which comes from practice and lots of it until you know what looks good to the end user.
I also suggest learning straight to xhtml, because it forces good syntax as has a wider range of possibilities.
Another piece of advice is: don't try learning the style in html, you'll end wasting your time when you realise it can be done much faster in CSS.

Comment: I've heard good and bad about the w3schools tutorials.  I'm concerned that they look like they cover core concepts, but break down on higher level design and architecture questions.  Do other people who're more knowledgable re: web dev't agree, or am I being unfair?

Comment: I was a software engineer looking to learn about web development and the first thing I did was run through the tutorials on w3schools for html, css, and javascript. It covered the bases and made the other readings (see PortageMonkey's answer) much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Designing With Web Standards by Jeffrey Zeldman is a very good introduction into front-end best practise. I would have to say John Resig's [Pro JavaScript Techniques](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-JavaScript-Techniques-John-Resig/dp/1590597273) is the best JavaScript book I've read. As for CSS, the above mentioned Bulletproof Web Design and Pro CSS Techniques (from the same publisher as Pro JavaScript Techniques) are excellent.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend "Javascript: The Good Parts" for an easy read while learning Javascript since you already know how to program.

Also check out this great intro to JS video of a talk at Northeastern last year:

[Javascript and jQuery](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-7485992465859932389)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers guys, to summarize it I've saved this list:

Javascript/AJAX:

- Javascript, the definitive guide
- W3schools (already reading)
- Pro JavaScript
- Douglas Crockford's series of lectures on javascript and the DOM
- Javascript, the good parts
- DOM Scripting
- Head First JavaScript
- Foundations of Ajax

CSS/HTML:

- CSS Mastery
- Pro CSS and HTML Design Patterns
- Head First HTML with CSS & XHTML

Web design:

- Bulletproof web design
- Designing With Web Standards

Comment: I won't recommend W3Schools. See this http://w3fools.com/